# memory allocation for stack vs primitive datatypes

Tags: c, memory-management, malloc

While declaring a structure in C, say:

```
typedef struct my_stuct {
 int x;
 float f;
} STRT;
```

If we want to create an instance of this struct and use it, we explicitly need to call malloc, get a pointer to the memory location for this struct before we can actually initialize/use any of the members of the structure:

```
STRT * my_struct_instance = (STRT *) (malloc(sizeof(STRT)));
```

However, if I declare a primitive data type (say "int a;") and then want to initialize it (or do any other operation to it), I do not need to explicitly assign mempory space for it by calling malloc before performing any operation on it:

```
// we do not need to do a malloc(sizeof(i)) blah blah here. Why?
i = 10;
```

Can you please explain what is the reason for this inconsistency? Thank you!

Comment: `STRT object;` works fine, though  the members will be uninitialized.

Comment: @chris `malloc` doesn't initialize members either, so that doesn't distinguish it automatic from dynamic allocation.

Comment: `STRT object = {3, 5};` there, initialised.

Comment: but I don't have to use malloc in order to be able to initialize the variables with primitive types. But I DO need to do that with a struct - why?

Comment: @delnan, Right you are. I'm just wondering why the impression that dynamic allocation must be used exists.

Comment: Or `= {}` to initialise all fields to zero.  Little trick that some people don't remember, so end up using `memset()` unnecessarily.

Comment: @user721998, `int i;` does NOT initialize `i` and `malloc` does not initialize it either.

Comment: @user721998 you don't. You can put `struct`s on the stack just like `int`s.

Comment: Oh, while we're at it, there's no need to cast the return value of `malloc` (and some argue it's bad, because it's redundant and can hide bugs). In C that is, not in C-compiled-as-C++.

Comment: @Griwes, This would be the place: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc

Comment: I think the OP needs to learn more about pointers.

Answer (score 7):

There is no inconsistency. Each of the two methods can be used both with primitives and with `structs`:

```
  STRT s1 = {1, 2};
  int i1 = 1;

  STRT *s2 = (STRT *)malloc(sizeof(STRT));
  int *i2 = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int));
  ...
```

Comment: Let's say I want to declare the stucture variable and initialize it in two seperate steps like this:

    STRT struct_var;
    struct_var->x = 10;
    struct_var->y = 10.0;

This would not work, unless I do not explicitly assign 'struct_var' a memory location using malloc().

However, you can easily do that in primitive data types as:

    int i;
    i=10;

Comment: @user721998, That's not initializing. That's assigning to the members.

Comment: @NPE: Replacing -> with . works, but why? Appreciate your help guys!

Comment: @user721998: `s->x` is the same as `(*s).x`, i.e. it only works if `s` is a pointer. Here, it isn't.

Comment: @user721998 In C, `.` is used to select a member of a struct (or union), as in `s1.x`. If `s1` is a pointer, you must dereference the pointer first, like `(*s1).x` . Doing this is so common that there's a shortcut (the `->` operator) for selecting a member of a pointer to a struct, so you can do `s1->x`

Answer (score 2):

you can do:

```
int i;
```

or

```
int *i = (int*) malloc(sizeof(int));
```

just like you can do

```
STRT my_struct_instance;
```

or

```
STRT * my_struct_instance = (STRT *) (malloc(sizeof(STRT)));
```

Answer (score 2):

In your malloc example, you are using pointers. The inconsistency, as you call it, is because a pointer can be initialized in several ways. It is not always initialized by a new memory allocations, but it can also be initialized to point at an existing memory block. So, it is not possible for the language to assume that the variable should be allocated on the heap:

```
STRT* my_struct_instance; // here I assume (incorrectly) that it is automatically allocated on the heap
my_struct_instance->x = 0; // ERROR: uninitialized use of that variable
```

Don't know if that answers your question.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it in both ways, there isn't any inconsistency.

**Heap**

```
int* a= malloc(sizeof(int));
*a=10;
STRT* b= malloc(sizeof(STRT));
b->x=1; 
b->f=1.0;
```

**Stack**

```
int a=10;
STRT b= {1, 1.0};
```

Comment: `*b= {1, 1.0};` are you sure?

Comment: you're welcome, maybe you meant compound literals `*b = (STRT){1, 1.0};` valid in C99

Answer (score 0):

```
STRT * my_struct_instance = (STRT *) (malloc(sizeof(STRT)));
```

uses dynamic storage;

```
int a;
```

uses automatic storage (I'm using C++ names right now, but it is probably called similarly in C). So, those are two completely different things. `int a;` is local, on (in most implementations) stack (although stack is not relevant implementation detail); `SRTR * [...]` is dynamic, on (in most implementations) heap (although, again, heap is not relevant implementation detail).

So, there is no inconsistency. Saying there is one is like saying that there is inconsistency between apples and oranges - but of course there is, since you are comparing apples and oranges. (The other parts of the question don't make sense, since they are based on assumption that apples and oranges are one and the same thing).